# Validate form with hidden fields

Tags: validation, hidden-field, jquery-validate

in my page there are few hidden field which are filled with the correct value from a script. These fields are validated server side against code injection and others malicius attacks but I'd like to put some code to validate the fields also client-side.
My aim is to request that field with name = "name1" and "name2" contain a string of two (not more not less) letters (not numbers) to submit the form.
My problem is that for the others fields I am using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 but if the field is hidden the script doesn't work on it.
I'm using the following code to tell validation which roles to follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules:{
            my_hidden_field:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                   }
        },
            messages:{
            my_hidden_field: "this field is not valid"
            },
        errorLabelContainer: "#BoxValidator",
        wrapper: "li",
    });
});
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Perhaps "How to validate hidden fields with jQuery Validation Plugin?" and "How to run verify into doesn't contain numbers...?" e.g.

Comment: I've deleted the second part of the question, keeping the most important and the most related with the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ignore: []` to validate hidden fields:

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules:{
        my_hidden_field:{
            required: true,
            minlength: 2,
               }
    },
    messages:{
        my_hidden_field: "this field is not valid"
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#BoxValidator",
    wrapper: "li",
    ignore: [] // <----
});
```